# the yahoo sign in popup doesn't last long or it says "the requested action is invalid"

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

[image]

```
const handleYahooSignIn = () => {
  signInWithPopup(auth, yahooProvider)
    .then(result => {
      const user = result.additionalUserInfo.profile
      console.log(user)
    })

}
```